# Using jQuery in a GreaseMonkey script for GMail

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script to change colours on the default GMail UI, using jQuery to select the element I want to change.  However, I'm having no end of difficulty getting thing working/debugged.  When I eventually corrected my "@requires" url, I found it very hard to identify which div, in a morass of billions of nested divs, is actually presenting the colour I want to change.  The majority of them are decorated with only one class, .nH,

It's the blue bar above the inbox I want to change.

I'm not seeing any errors anymore, but my GM_Log call seems to be ignored, and jQuery is not defined.  I suspect the latter problem is that GreaseMonkey has unloaded jQuery once my user script has executed.  Am I even close?  It would be nice if I could test selectors in the console window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can load jquery into the page using [jquerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet).  This should allow you to figure out the selector needed in the GM query.  You might also try out [selector gadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) which is an easy tool for coming up with rules to select elements on a page.

Comment: Unfortunately, SelectorGadget doesn't seem to work on mail.google.com, but granted, Gmail is a different animal altogether.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually discovered jQuerify late last night, but I gave up when trying to select a "div class='qm'" with $("div.qm") and getting nothing back. :-(

Comment: Probably you didn't get the tag because google use iframe. So, first get the content window of iframe and then the corresponding tag.

Comment: If you use Firefox + Firebug, you should install FireQuery (a Firebug plugin), which includes jqueryfy (and other great features).

Answer (score 2):

If you copy and paste the following into the javascript console in Chrome you will see an example of loading jQuery and executing a query.  Hopefully that helps but honestly, Googles HTML/CSS is a moving target and anything you make may end up unstable.

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(scr);

// wait for the script to load before doing this line
jQuery(document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentDocument).find('.nU a.n0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect extension to embed jQuery into Chrome Console as simple as you can imagine. This extension also indocates if jQuery has been already embeded into page.

This extension used to embed jQuery into any page you want. It allows to use jQuery in the console shell (You can invoke Chrome console by "Ctrl+Shift+j").

To embed jQuery into selected tab click on extention button.

*LINK* to extension:
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your code, so we can see what may be not working?

Also, here is a link to one of my scripts that uses JQuery, so you can look at the source to check how to do it.

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77701

PS: If you reinstall the script, the @require is downloaded again. I tested it.

Answer (score -1):

As to how to use jQuery in Greasemonkey:

```
// @require http://www.example.com/example.js
```

More info at: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require

Or to use jQuery in Chrome: http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/14/using-jquery-with-a-user-script